# Rating system using CSS (hover from left to right)

Tags: css

Is there a simple way to reverse the colour order when hovering?

Using this trick here I have the order right > left:

```
&:hover,
&:hover ~ button {
    color: red
}
```

The fiddle with the right > left: https://jsfiddle.net/celio/Lowc1ruh/

Example with the left > right: https://css-tricks.com/examples/StarRating/

It is impossible for me to use `float`, `position: absolute;` and anything that changes the right order of my current html.

**Plain CSS example:**

```css
button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}
button:before {
  content: "⋆";
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 1;
}
button:hover,
button:hover ~ button {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button></button>
  <button id="2"></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to make all the child `button` elements `color: red;` when hovering over `.wrapper`. Then use the sibling selector (`~`) to change any elements after the currently hovered element to `color: black;`.

You should remove any whitespace between the elements (in this case I put them into one line in the HTML) to ensure that the cursor is always hovering over a star.

**Example with plain CSS:**

```css
.wrapper button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper button:before {
  content: "⋆";
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 1;
}
.wrapper button:hover ~ button {
  color: black;
}
.wrapper:hover button {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button></button><button id="2"></button><button></button><button></button><button></button>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle using SASS](https://jsfiddle.net/v873dqf2/1/)

Comment: You did it and by the clever way. Thanks a lot! @HiddenHobbes

Comment: @HiddenHobbes you can also set `font-size:0` on the `.wrapper` element to eliminate the white space with CSS. Just make sure you redefine it later (which you do).

Comment: @easwee Yup that would work too and as the `font-size` is already being redefined for the pseudo element it is probably the preferable way to do it in this instance.